# Rails Jump to a Certain Area on the Page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scroll

I am having a hard time finding an answer to this...

I have a few anchor tags at the top of my view. I would like those to simply link (or scroll in this case) to another area on the page. For example, if one clicks the "Side effects" link, I would like it to take them to the side effects location on the page, without redirected of course.

What is the best way to go about this? Javascript?

Here are is my view:

```
<div class="quick_links well">
  <h2>Jump to:</h2>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#">Short answer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Long answer</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Side effects</a></li>
  </ol>
</div>  

<div class="content">
  <h2>Short Answer<h2>
  <p>blah blah blah</p>

  <h2>Long Answer<h2>
  <p>blah blah blah</p>

  <h2>Side effects<h2>
  <p>blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

If there is already an answer to this, please point me in that direction. I am having an overly hard time finding anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oooh I know this one! Add an id to each of the elements on the page you want to jump to and then set the href of your links to the id of the element that link jumps to. Note this it how Wikipedia's section links work

```
<div class="quick_links well">
   <h2>Jump to:</h2>
   <ol>
       <li><a href="#short-answer">Short answer</a></li>
       <li><a href="#long-answer">Long answer</a></li>
       <li><a href="#side-effects">Side effects</a></li>
   </ol>
</div>  

<div class="content">
   <h2 id="short-answer">Short Answer<h2>
   <p>blah blah blah</p>

   <h2 id="long-answer">Long Answer<h2>
   <p>blah blah blah</p>

   <h2 id="side-effects">Side effects<h2>
   <p>blah blah blah</p>
</div>
```

This will allow you to jump to the linked section when the link is clicked, you can use javascript to to make the webpag smoothly scroll down to the linked element.

As ever css tricks comes to the resccue with a guide on [how to implement smooth scrolling to links](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/)

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to have it done using Rails `link_to` tag then do the following:

```
<%= link_to 'Short Answer', "#{pages_welcome_path}#short_answer" %>
<%= link_to 'Long Answer', "#{pages_welcome_path}#long_answer" %>
<%= link_to 'Side Effects', "#{pages_welcome_path}#side_effects" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an anchor attribute to the `link_to` tag in Rails to make it even cleaner.

`link_to 'Comments', public_topic_entry_path(@topic, @entry, anchor: "comments-title")`